# What is the importance of studying degeneration on $M_g$

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $M_g$ be the moduli space of smooth curves of genus $g$. Let $\overline{M_g}$ be its compactification; the moduli space of stable curves of genus $g$.

It seems to be important in physics to study the degeneration of certain functions on $\overline{M_g}$ as you approach its boundary.

For which functions on $M_g$ is it interesting to physicists to study their degeneration as you approach the boundary?

I know of theta functions, Green functions and delta invariants. Are there others?

As in my other question, here is an [article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-137/issue-3/The-asymptotics-of-the-Arakelov-Greens-function-and-Faltings-delta/cmp/1104202735.full) by Wentworth which I find interesting.

Comment: This old question of mine over at MathOverflow might be relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/q/1312/